# Laravel validation value in array - livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a array of states that is looping in the front-end. I want to validate in the backend that the value is inside the array. I keep getting error that The selected state is invalid.

**Blade View**

```
<select wire:model.defer="state" name="state">
    @foreach($states as $state)
        <option value="{{ $state }}">{{ strtoupper($state) }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**Controller** (Livewire)

```
public $states = [
    'sa', 'vic', 'nsw', 'qld', 'act', 'nt', 'wa', 'tas'
];


protected function rules()
{
    $array = [
    'state' => 'required|in:$this->states',
    ];

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
protected function rules()
{
    $array = [
    'state' => 'required|in:'.implode(',',$this->states),
    ];

    return $array;
}
```

or

```
  protected function rules()
    {
        $array = [
        'state' => ['required',Rule::in($this->states)],
        ];
    
        return $array;
    }
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in

Answer (score 0):

Or if your just looking for a basic validation method/function for states, it's really just a string validation helper regardless of the framework. Here we use U.S. state codes. The principle is the same.

```
/**
 * Validate State code strings
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getValidStates($str) {
    $states = array(
        "AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","HI",
        "ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN",
        "MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH",
        "OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA",
        "WV","WI","WY","AS","GU","MP","PR","VI","FM","MH","PW"
    );

    if (in_array(strtoupper($str), $states)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```